# UPDATE SQL TABLE With Identity Column Using GridView Update

Tags: asp.net, sql, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to update a table that has and indentity column. So when I try to update a row in gridview I get the following error "Cannot update identity column 'ManufactureID'.]" I know you can insert the updated row and then delete the old row.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False"     DataKeyNames="Name" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" EmptyDataText="There are no data records to display.">
        <Columns>
            <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" ShowEditButton="True" ShowSelectButton="True" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ManufactureID" HeaderText="ManufactureID" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ManufactureID" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Address" HeaderText="Address" SortExpression="Address" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Providence" HeaderText="Providence" SortExpression="Providence" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="City" HeaderText="City" SortExpression="City" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ZipCode" HeaderText="ZipCode" SortExpression="ZipCode" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Country" HeaderText="Country" SortExpression="Country" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Phone" HeaderText="Phone" SortExpression="Phone" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Fax" HeaderText="Fax" SortExpression="Fax" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Email" HeaderText="Email" SortExpression="Email" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:GreatGrizzlyConnectionString1 %>" DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [Manufacturer] WHERE [Name] = @Name" InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [Manufacturer] ([Name], [Address], [Providence], [City], [ZipCode], [Country], [Phone], [Fax], [Email]) VALUES (@Name, @Address, @Providence, @City, @ZipCode, @Country, @Phone, @Fax, @Email)" ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SQLTestConnectionString1.ProviderName %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [ManufactureID], [Name], [Address], [Providence], [City], [ZipCode], [Country], [Phone], [Fax], [Email] FROM [Manufacturer]" UpdateCommand="UPDATE [Manufacturer] SET [ManufactureID] = @ManufactureID, [Address] = @Address, [Providence] = @Providence, [City] = @City, [ZipCode] = @ZipCode, [Country] = @Country, [Phone] = @Phone, [Fax] = @Fax, [Email] = @Email WHERE [Name] = @Name">
        <DeleteParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="Name" Type="String" />
        </DeleteParameters>
        <InsertParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="Name" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Address" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Providence" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="City" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="ZipCode" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Country" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Phone" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Fax" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Email" Type="String" />
        </InsertParameters>
        <UpdateParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="ManufactureID" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Address" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Providence" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="City" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="ZipCode" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Country" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Phone" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Fax" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Email" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Name" Type="String" />
        </UpdateParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Answer (score 0):

The statement specified in the `UpdateCommand` attribute of your `<asp:SqlDataSource>` tag tries to set the [ManufactureID], that's why you're getting the error:

`UpdateCommand="UPDATE [Manufacturer] SET [ManufactureID] = @ManufactureID, [Address] = @Address, [Providence] = @Providence, [City] = @City, [ZipCode] = @ZipCode, [Country] = @Country, [Phone] = @Phone, [Fax] = @Fax, [Email] = @Email WHERE [Name] = @Name"`

You need to remove `[ManufactureID] = @ManufactureID,` and also remove `<asp:Parameter Name="ManufactureID" Type="Int32" />` from under `<UpdateParameters>`, that should do the trick.